# Cycles: out of SVM stack space, shader "" too big

Tags: python, shaders, shader-nodes, osl

Any idea on how to increase this? Im working with a rather large node tree and adding #noise.random() as an input value looks like the straw that broke the camels back. I'm able to get it to work if I switch cycles device to CPU with OSL enabled but that will take soooo much longer to render this.

Comment: are you mixing diffuse shaders? One way to to keep the stack space a bit lower (and to make it render faster too), is to not mix the diffuse shaders, but to mix the colors that you plug into the diffuse shader.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie would a diffuse shader be a MixRGB?

Comment: *MixRGB* node and *Diffuse Shader* node are different nodes.